# Value providers in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working with **ASP.NET MVC 5**

I am trying to understand the difference between `Model Binder` and `Value Provider`. I am confuse when to use `Model Provider` and when to use `Value Provider`. As per my understanding, I understood that if you want to map `XML` posted data to `CLR` object then use `Custom Model` provider, but I am still confused about the use of `Custom Value` provider.

So I need help on this.

Comment: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/06/30/whatrsquos-the-difference-between-a-value-provider-and-model-binder.aspx/

Comment: I have gone through the article in the link but unable to understand because I have not found any implementation there. My need is I want to understand its use in MVC application development. Can I use it read intercept the incomming request header and read information in it to log it in Database?

Comment: For that I would rely on Asp.Net Mvc filter infrastructure